# Moveit Python Demo causes [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Tags: moveit, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS Community,

This is my first post to this forum.  I am attempting to run the tutorial for moveit using python. Specifically the Move Group Interface/Python API tutorial.  Sorry, my karma is not yet good enough to post links.

- I am running python 2.7.
- OS is Ubuntu 12.04
- ROS and ROS packages are installed using apt-get

I have created a package called my_youbot_moveit with a simple python script.  The script contains the following:

```
import sys
import copy
import rospy
import moveit_commander
import moveit_msgs.msg
import geometry_msgs.msg

print("============ Starting tutorial setup")
moveit_commander.roscpp_initialize(sys.argv)
rospy.init_node('move_group_python_interface_tutorial', anonymous=True)
```

When I run the code

```
source ~/catkin/develop/setup.bash
rosrun my_youbot_moveit my_youbot_moveit.py
```

I get the error

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_base.py", line 153, in run
    (client_sock, client_addr) = self.server_sock.accept()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 202, in accept
    sock, addr = self._sock.accept()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 170, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Please help me understand what is causing this problem and how to solve it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173746/moveit-python-demo-causes-%5Berrno-9%5D-bad-file-descriptor/) by [Rick C NIST](https://answers.ros.org/users/18890/rick-c-nist/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2014-06-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rick C NIST](https://answers.ros.org/users/18890/rick-c-nist/) on 2014-06-25**:
I reran the moveit setup assistant, and this problem went away.  Must have been an error in one of my configuration files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I reran the moveit setup assistant, and this problem went away. Must have been an error in one of my configuration files

---

Originally posted by [Rick C NIST](https://answers.ros.org/users/18890/rick-c-nist/) with karma: 28 on 2014-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0